# Write caffe architecture in matlab

Tags: matlab, caffe, matcaffe

Has anyone an idea how one could write caffe architectures using matlab?
In python there are caffe mods (eg [ApolloCaffe](http://apollocaffe.com/)) where you can get the  corresponding prototxt string by typing for example:

```
datalayer = HDF5Data('myDataLayer', 'data_train.txt', 250, tops=['data', 'label'])
iplayer1 = InnerProduct('ip1',4000,bottoms=["data"])
relu1 = ReLU('relu1',tops=["ip1"],bottoms=["ip1"])
iplayer2 = InnerProduct('ip2',25,bottoms=["ip1"])
losslayer = SoftmaxWithLoss('loss', bottoms=['ip2', 'label'])
```

Like this one can easily build various caffe architectures without hardcoding them which has the danger of making copy-paste errors.

Is there something similar for Matlab?

Comment: I'm looking for this as well. Any progress?

Comment: Not yet unfortunately. Seems like one has to write it themself ;). Deeplab has some bash scripts that at least permit to change some variables automatically. MatConvNet is supposed to be easier too

Comment: I don't like MatConvNet. It is not well documented and the code, in my opinion, is not one which invite you to digg in.